# Should I force enable hardware acceleration in the browser?

Tags: firefox, chromium

Neither firefox nor chromium have hardware acceleration enabled by default right now. Firefox 4 has an option its registry to force it:  `layers.acceleration.force.enabled` , which is  by default set to false.

Having passed all but 3 of 800 tests run by [the grafx bot](http://jagriffin.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/introducting-grafx-bot/), I thought it reasonable to set the above registry entry to true. However I get a terrible score in the FPS test at [the mozilla hardware acceleration stress test](http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/HWACCEL/). But it doesn't seem to give any problems in normal usage.

Similarly gpu acceleration can be enabled in Chromium 10 by navigating to about:flags and checking the option. So, should I enable it or not?

Comment: For anybody reading this in the distant future: the key has moved to `layers.acceleration.force-enabled`

Comment: I just turned it on and my score went from 60 (my screen limit) to 19... And I have a Nvidia GTX 580 in here. If that's anything to go by, I'd say it's not ready yet :)

Comment: As of Chromium 11, enabling gpu-accelerated-compositing gives me a score of 30fps. Also within about:flags are options for an fps counter and a frame to indicate when layers are being accelerated, but disappointingly average webpages seem not to be participating. One benchmark I found that makes use of acceleration is [Speed Reading](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/SpeedReading/Default.html)   at Microsoft's IE demo page

Comment: Using the nvidia 275 drivers from the xswat ppa on 10.04 and using Firefox 6b2 I get 30fps in the stress test now. Only drivers after 270 are supposed to be whitelisted in the new firefox, so rather than manually whitelist the 196 drivers I bit the bullet and upgraded and they work well.

Comment: The above was with *without* acceleration on (according to about:support). With layers.acceleration.force-enabled=1 it's back down to 17. At the time of the original question I only got six fps. The fishtank demo bears out these figures. The most annoying thing for me is that scrolling is still very jerky. A €40 smartphone can manage this! Soon Chromium will have smooth scrolling and Opera is already pretty good so fingers X'd Mozilla.

Comment: Chromium 15 is back down 6fps. on a similar windows machine I get 60+ fps

Comment: Actually.. if I override the software rendering list on the chrome://flags page I get 60+fps.

Answer (score 2):

I have it enabled on both on my system. However, since mileage may vary, I would suggest trying it out for a while before you set it and forget it, so to speak :).

In short, yes.